# Print String as pattern in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I am from OO background and very new to Haskell. 
In order to print a pattern like:

```
1 2 3 4 5
1 2 3 4
1 2 3
1 2
1
```

i made a list

```
let xs = ["1 2 3 4 5\n"
         ,"1 2 3 4\n"
         ,"1 2 3\n"
         ,"1 2\n"
         ,"1\n"]
```

But i get the output like

```
["1 2 3 4 5\n","1 2 3 4\n","1 2 3\n","1 2\n","1\n"]
```

How can i get the desired output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just to elaborate a bit, you can do both things together like this:

```
ghci> putStrLn $ unlines $ ["1 2 3 4 5"
                           ,"1 2 3 4"
                           ,"1 2 3"
                           ,"1 2"
                           ,"1"]
```

**$** has a very low precedence and is right associative so this will behave in the same way as

```
ghci> (putStrLn (unlines ["1 2 3 4 5"
         ,"1 2 3 4"
         ,"1 2 3"
         ,"1 2"
         ,"1"]))
```

Comment: Very uncommon to see two `$`s in one expression: usually this would be written `putStrLn . unlines $ [...]`

Comment: Why not as `putStrLn $ unlines [...]` ?

Answer (score 8):

To add more built-in goodies:

You don't need to manually produce the lines for a pattern like this:

```
triangle :: Int -> String
triangle n = unlines . map (unwords . map show) $ [[1 .. k] | k <- [n, n-1 .. 1]]

Prelude> putStr $ triangle 7
1 2 3 4 5 6 7
1 2 3 4 5 6
1 2 3 4 5
1 2 3 4
1 2 3
1 2
1

import Data.List (intersperse)

triangleOf :: [Char] -> Int -> String
triangleOf chars n = unlines . map (intersperse ' ') $ [take k chars | k <- [n, n-1 .. 1]]

Prelude Data.List> putStr $ triangleOf "Haskell" 7
H a s k e l l
H a s k e l
H a s k e
H a s k
H a s
H a
H
```

You can get other patterns for example using `takeWhile (not . null) (tails chars)`, there are plenty of variations.

Answer (score 5):

The short answer is

```
mapM_ putStr xs
```

Basically this executes the [action](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Introduction_to_Haskell_IO/Actions) `putStr` for each member of your list. That is, it takes each string in `xs` and prints it out.

Incidentally, the output you're seeing from `show xs` is a valid Haskell expression - you could pass it to the `read` function to recreate `xs`.

Comment: Imperative programmers may find themselves comfortable using `forM_`, which is equivalent to `mapM_` but with the inputs swapped. E.g. `forM_ [1..10] print`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the unlines function to turn a list of strings into a single string with '\n' as deliminator. It's like a .join('\n')

```
unlines ["1", "2", "3"]
```

yields

```
"1\n2\n3\n"
```

Then you can print it using putStrLn (only prints strings) or print (prints all objects)

Answer (score 0):

```
import Data.List

putStr $ unlines $ map (unwords.(map show)) $ reverse $ inits [1..5]
```